# Completely reset a css class inside @media screen

Tags: css, reset

I have a menu bar for the main site which has a lot of CSS, but for smartphone users I want to completely redesign the menu bar. I am doing this by using `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}` and changing the properties of the classes there, however everything is being inherited from the original class and it's a real pain to reset every single property on every class manually.

So I was wondering if there is an easy way to reset a class in CSS when using `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}`

Comment: What framework you are using?

Comment: WordPress with Genesis framework. In the end I had to do it manually. Was a massive trial and error run. Most properties I reset to ```auto```.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a property called `all` for resetting all CSS properties.

```
.classname {
    all: initial; /* or unset */
}
```

> **initial** - This keyword indicates to change all the properties applying to the element or the element's parent to their initial value...
>
> **unset** - This keyword indicates to change all the properties applying to the element or the element's parent to their parent value if they are inheritable or to their initial value if not...

Browser support: Chrome 37+, Firefox 27+, IE 11+, Safari Not supported

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for, unfortunately since the support for browsers is so low, especially with IE, in the end I had to do it manually. Was a massive pain and I am still not 100% through with the reset. Hopefully in 2-3 years this can be used as a standard.

Comment: Instead of resetting every property I would rather create a second navigation, include the same content to both navigations and hide the main navigation in the @media query.

Comment: @Chris. sounds good to me, I do that sometimes too, but it also depending on the CMS if OP uses any that allows to do it. Feel free to post it as an answer if you like.