# How to disable the effect of a CSS class on a nested element?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way or woukaround to specify a CSS class in a way that it only affects certain nested elements? In the example let's suppose that the **.rich-text** class has some CSS rules. I would want to achieve that it applies to everything inside that div except the **.inner** div and all it's descendants.

```
<div class="rich-text">
    <div class="random">
        <div class="inner">
            The rich-text class should not effect this or anything in it
        </div>
        <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I see that there are some answers that try to give a solution to this exact example code. I would need a general solution that works no matter where the inner class is at (it could be 2 or 20 levels deep and so on...).

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495793/completely-reset-a-css-class-inside-media-screen

Comment: That depends upon what CSS you are trying to disable.  It is just best to define all of the `inner` CSS explicitly.

Comment: You could use `.rich-text :not(.inner)` as your .rich-text rule.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the rules for `.inner` and all it's descendants back to `initial`.

```css
.rich-text {
  color:red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.inner, .inner > * {
  color: initial;
  font-family: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="rich-text">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="inner">The rich-text class should make no effect on this and everything inside it.<h1>Foo</h1></div>
    <p>Some text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write the indexed class name right after the root.

So for example in your case you want `inner` class to only apply to `random` which has to be within `rich-text`.

```
.rich-text .random .inner {
    color: red;
}
```

The red text color would only apply to any element with the `inner` class applied which has to be within a element with a  `random` class which has to be within a element with `rich-text` class.

This would apply to anything that follows that hierarchy but bare in mind that it doesn't have to be directly following it. Another way to put it is that you can still have a `something` class inbetween `random` and `rich-text` and the red text would still work.

If you want it to be a strict hierarchy then you can simply use `>` which means that it has to directly follow the given matches.

```
.rich-text > .random > .inner {
    color: red;
}
```

Would ONLY apply the red text color if the `inner` class is within `random` within `rich-text` and it has to follow that hierarchy and can't have anything else inbetween

Comment: I think your answer is a bit of a reverse of what I expect. I would like to define rules for the .rich-text class. And I would like to make these rules not to affect anything in the .inner class.

Comment: In that case you could always still use the `:not()` selector
`.rich-text:not(.inner)`

This should give you a idea of how it actually works: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: Unfortunately I would need this to be supported in IE 8 as well.

Comment: Besides the easy way out which would be overriding the `.inner` class with the preset styles, I'm not too sure how to do it then I'm afraid. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, you have to use the direct children css selector (and not deeper) :

```
.rich-text > *
```

It means the rules are only applied to the direct children of .rich-text.